# Animal to have as an efficiently modified enemy to humans

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, fauna, zoology

I am trying to think of animals that would make the strongest enemy for humans if they were bred in a laboratory.

My goal is to have an animal that begins by being used in a benign, controlled way, but can go rogue under the right circumstances (which I'm still working at).

I need animals that would, preferably, be naturally loners but would tolerate others of the same kind for some time.

They should be strong and trainable because I need them to originally be used by police/army forces for **rescues and crowd control**. They would need to be able to drag a fully grown man, climb unstable surfaces, dig...

All that come to my mind are tigers and lions, maybe bears as well but am not sure if they could, with some minor tweaking, be at all usable, or which kind would tolerate it better.

If tigers, lions and/or bears are the best answer then please point that out.

Hybrids could work as well if they could be created in a laboratory only.

P.S. - If I wanted the traditional dog or horse I would use those. I need animals naturally so fierce they would serve as psychological deterrents during crowd control.

Comment: Please try to avoid "best" and use as objective terms as possible.

Comment: Give me a swimming pool, and I will fight a T-rex bare hand

Comment: I would argue you can genetically modify a dog so it turns into a cat. If you want trainable and used in the police force, you should be stuck with what is already in the police force, I believe mainly horses or dogs. If you want as deadly as possible (and you can claim trainable via genetic modification), go with some insect like creature. Mosquitoes are very good in theory at killing people. The tick is one sneaky bastard. Spiders are also great. Really anything small and disgusting

Comment: @Raditz_35: _T. rex_ could probably swim

Comment: "All that come to my mind are tigers and lions, maybe bears" --oh my!

Comment: @Raditz_35 how would you use a mosquito to drag a fully grown human man out of a building in danger of crumbling over whatever/whoever goes in to attempt the rescue?

Comment: @F1Krazy if you know of any other large animals with similar characteristics please tell me what they are, those are exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Your comment makes me wonder if you have put more thought into your question but decided not to tell us about the details for some reason. If you have certain characteristics an animal has to fulfill, for example being able to carry a human being or whatever excludes horses, dogs, lions, bears or tigers, please state them in your question

Comment: are you trying to find actual living animals or can they imaginary/extinct animals ?

Comment: I would like to note that several things (e.g: title) aren't quite clear and don't straight-forwardly tell us what it is you are looking for.

Comment: @shieldedtulip In an effort to save your question from being closeable I removed the option of GE, which makes this question too broad and too opinionative

Answer (score 9):

**Man's intelligence is his greatest weapon**

Because of that, no "animal" is superior to man no matter how beastly you make it. The only way to beat man is to make a more intelligent being.

Anyways since that rules out GE, because why not just make an superior intelligence chimera.

**I'd pick Polar Bears** They have the high intelligence (problem solving), they are trainable, they are mean, and just like a grizzly bear can rip your face off on a moments notice.

They can dig (its how they hunt baby seals)

They have superior smell

they are expert swimmers

Just like other bears they can take a heck of a beating and just get angrier

Comment: Polar bears are carnivorous, not omnivorous.

Comment: I thought all bears are omnivorous, theres just no green up there for them to eat

Comment: Upon some quick googling, I don't think anyones tried to feed a polar bear fruit and see that happens

Comment: They eat all sorts of human food waste as available, WWF also says they eat seaweed.

Comment: what about human slaves? Plenty of times in history they decided to view certain peoples as a different species and used them for all sorts of dirty work including police duty and crowd control.

Comment: @Kilisi - hmm, arming slaves? Sure, that'll work. What could ever go wrong with that?

Comment: @LeeLeon ever heard of the [Chela?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chela_(Mughal_army)). or the [Mamluks?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamluk) , ancient history but in more modern times the French used Turkish prisoners in the penal colonies as trustee overseers to the french prisoners. Probably plenty of others.

Comment: @Kilisi - I'd heard of the Mamluks, but not the Chela - you make a good point, but these are different times, and slaves are still humans so technically excluded from any solution. +1 though

Answer (score 8):

#### Komodo dragon

As a mad scientist I would definitely go for these amazing beasts.

[image]
(Photo: Sergey Uryadnikov/Shutterstock)

I can already see police officers controlling an entire crownd with one of these **3m long** dragon in leash. No one will mess with them as Komodo dragon is one of the few **venomous lizard**. A bite from them and if the wound is not treated as soon as possible, local **necrosis** can rapidly develop, which may require (in the worst case) an amputation of the affected limb.

I'm not sure they can be used for rescue operations but their claws can still be useful to dig and find some buried people. Wild Komodos dragons sometimes dig graves to unearth human cadavers and can **dig galleries up to 1.3 m wide**...

Tamed, they could be great at finding fugitive peoples as they are able to follow creatures they bit for days until they died from necrosis. Futhermore, they can run up to **20 km/h** which is pretty fast for an animal of this size.

They are also lonely hunters, but tolerate to feed in groups, as you asked.

Finally, I think you can easily imagine if these beast become smarter and bigger by genetic mutations and one day decide to go rampage ;)

Comment: I was thinking of these as well, but had the same doubt, what if they hurt a person they are trying to rescue?

Comment: Technically, the dragon is not venomous;  it just has really bad oral hygiene...

Comment: @DJohnM In fact Komodo dragons do have two glands in the lower jaw that produce venom. But you are right, there is still a debate about which of the venom (which is not that strong) or the bacterias of its mouth is the most involved in killing.

Comment: @shieldedtulip Maybe they could wear a muzzle ? So they would dig to find people but wouldn't be able to bite ? Claws are still an issue of course but not as much as their bite.

Comment: @shieldedtulip muzzles.... big dogs were used to take down poachers and were muzzled so they couldn't kill the poachers before the Lord could hang them in public... bull mastiffs were one breed I think.

Comment: Muzzles and gloves as well maybe ;)

Answer (score 5):

The mega armadillo **Glyptodon**.
They would have to be resurrected via lab or artificially reconstructed. They are naturally armored (could be lab enhanced) so they might make good cover for personnel in a gun fight. They went extinct 11,000 years ago. So you can give them the temperament and intelligence your story needs. If you do artificially enhance them to be bullet proof it makes them better human predators.

http://www.prehistoric-wildlife.com/species/g/glyptodon.html

Genetically enhanced (for size) **badger**.  They are fierce creatures and loners as well. They just need to be a little bit bigger.

Comment: Badger!!! Yes, I kinda like that one, very hufflepuffish ;)

Answer (score 5):

Two big potentials stand out for me:

1. Hornets + ants
2. Hyper-intelligent large cats

**Pros of the hornets-ants tag-team**:

- natural team players
- Can be controlled by pheromones, so you can coat your friendly units in 'no-touch' scent and then deploy them simultaneously
- Super cheap to replenish
- Individuals drones can't reproduce, so you don't have to worry about misplacing a few of those
- 100,000 ants can lift extremely heavy things with ease and can move dirt very quickly
- hornets would be insanely good at scattering a riot (biggest danger would be people injuring themselves trying to flee)
- (rogue) very, very difficult to permanently eradicate ants and hornets from a region

**Cons of the hornet-ants tag-team**:

- people are very scared of hornets, so it'll be harder to deploy them for minor things
- OP seems to want creatures that are individually strong and loners by preference

Additional notes:

- have to make the hornet venom very localized and hypo-allergenic to avoid killing people
- have to make the 'no-touch' scent specific to a colony so that the protestors can't duplicate it

Seriously though, just imagine hundreds of hornets going straight for exposed skin, intelligently crawling into clothing, targeting limbs and groin...
like demonic flying Chihuahuas whose bite paralyzes and introduces you to new meanings of the word 'pain'.

***On to the murder kitties!***

**Pros of the hyper-intelligent lions**:

- very strong
- good carry instincts (just have to get them to pick up humans by something other than the neck)
- good intimidation factor
- (rogue) cats are *to this day* known for hunting and killing humans. Bears, wolves, sharks, etc. do kill humans, but it's extremely rare for them to stalk and kill us. Cats... known examples have racked up dozens of attacks and were very difficult to track down
- (rogue) big cats seem to develop a taste for human flesh once they start trying it

**Cons of the hyper-intelligent lions**:

- not the greatest at working together
- how do you get a cat to follow orders?
- ^^^
- seriously though, how?
- even Romans learned not to keep uncaged/untethered lions around the house...

Comment: It's worth noting that in the wild lion prides *absolutely* hunt co-operatively.

Answer (score 3):

How about a larger double sized version of a [velociraptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velociraptor)? It would take a lot of genetic engineering, but starting with something like an ostrich it might be doable given enough time and technology.

Better still perhaps (and much more accessible) how about a large silverback gorilla?

[image: Gorilla Gorilla Gorilla]

[source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Gorilla#/media/File:Bristol.zoo.western.lowland.gorilla.arp.jpg)

genetic engineering and breeding could concentrate on ensuring the beast had the temperament you are looking for. Probably quite good at crowd control and climbing and should be capable of some digging as well if engineered a little.

Comment: Twice the size of a turkey is still pretty small. From the Wikipedia article you linked: *"In real life, however, Velociraptor was roughly the size of a turkey, considerably smaller than the approximately 2 m (7 ft) tall 80 kg (180 lb) reptiles seen in the films."* ("The films" referring to the Jurassic Park films.)

Comment: I think that link should go to [utahraptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utahraptor).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I think its mouth is going to be up at around chest level, its going to be able to move very quickly and it will have some nasty teeth and claws. If the film Jurassic park were still in the popular imagination it might also have an effect out of proportion to its actual effectiveness. Not something that I would want to tangle with in any sort of crowd control situation, but maybe the gorilla would be more effictive.

Comment: Gorillas are a good idea, but they are gregarious animals, not sure if they would turn on their human friends. But I like the ostrich idea...

Comment: @shieldedtulip Yes true Gorillas would not be ideal "as is", but with a ittle genetic engineering it might work. Infact breeding might do, just by picking the largest and most agressive from ech generation. As has been done with rats: https://www.newscientist.com/blogs/shortsharpscience/2011/08/beyond-room-101-the-hyperaggre.html

Answer (score 3):

**Official brochure:** Meet the latest product of Monsanto Labs, the bio-engineered Best-Buddy! Gifted with an easy-going and peaceful personality, it will obey your every order.

Its razor-sharp mandibles have no trouble shearing cars and trucks, which make it a very good team player when the time comes to extract a careless driver from a heap of bent steel. They can dig, burrow, and feel at ease in earthquake rescue scenarios (in tests, only 2% of rescued victims were missing limbs).

[image]

Nah, really, we found an egg inside an asteroid and this came out, so we patented it, of course. We control them with radio waves, since they seem to be telepathic. Of course, we never considered what would happen if some brain bug came along to control them all...

Comment: Spiders ARE scary lol, they would be great at crow control, but the chewing through metal doesn't work for me, if those things went rogue where would humans hide?

Comment: @shieldedtulip this is where these bugs come from ;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VywKJSglL24

Comment: Yep :3 I knew it lol. Loved that film, just couldn't remember the title, and did enjoy watching the TV cartoon series as well. But those giant spider things are still too much for my ppor humans with their fleshy bodies.

Comment: On the plus side, they're excellent for "crowd control" ;)

Comment: What better way to control a crowd than to make easy meals out of them? :P Yeah... I can see some extreme government doing that

Comment: @peufeu that's one scary critter you have there.  I might have to suggest that these guys are **too** scary for effective crowd control.  They'd cause a panicked flight, or possibly (I mentioned this in another answer to this Q) a "kill it with fire" reaction.  I do like the S&R aspect though!

Comment: Yeah, it was a bit of a joke, but... since OP needs ways for things to go wrong... Think about what kind of GM pets a merger between Weyland-Yutani (Aliens franchise) and Monsanto (who else) would produce... What could possibly go wrong? http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2017-11-09/monsanto-court-again-powerful-new-herbicide-accidently-kills-36-million-acres-crops

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you right, you would need to start with the oldest Cats, and the oldest Dogforms known. Then you could try a horizontal Gentransfer via Retrovirus, but i would stick to reverse form Breeding, to get them in a Genetic State as near to each other as possible, till they can have living Childs together. From that point on, you can add a few things per controlled Mutation, like Size (Grizzley) hard stinking fluids (Skunks) defensive Fur (Erinaceidae) and Ultrasonic "View" (Bats).

A being like that, would be feared and deadly for Mankind

Answer (score 2):

I think elephants are good. If you are going to genetically alter them, you could make them a bit smaller (maybe half, or a third, the size), but otherwise they seem ideal: they are intelligent, trainable, relatively tough - ideal for assisting in crowd control, with a trunk, which could also be genetically enhanced to be able to handle and restrain individuals, as required.

They are also non-carnivorous which is probably advantageous because, although they can intimidate, they are not going to actually take a bite out of anyone.

Rogue elephants are, however, quite formidable.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.  You need something intimidating, something that even angry crowds won't want to fight with.  But not so alien that the "kill it with fire!" reaction kicks in.

Which makes me think ... porcupines.  They are not psychotically aggressive, but it is almost always a mistake to fight with them.  They're even stylish:

[image: Is he not cute?]

So have your lab scale up porcupines -- maybe cross them with dogs, say labrador retrievers, to bump up their social affinity and ability to work together without increasing their aggression too much.

See, that's the thing.  If they are created for benign purposes, you don't **want** too aggressive an animal.  You want an animal that can "herd" humans without hurting them, but that can absolutely hurt those who want to fight:

[image: Don't Poke the 'Pine]

And if one of these guys *does* go rogue, he can jack up a *lot* of people.  Especially if you alter the spines so they contain poison or "knockout" drugs...

Comment: Ouch!!!  Very effective looking.

Answer (score 1):

Try chimpanzees. Stronger than humans, More intelligent than most animals . Even have a limited ability to use tools. Can be trained to communicate with humans on limted level . And have shown that they Can easily overpower and kill a human, However don't regard humans is some sort primary source of food so less likely to  Not attack on command .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an Amoeba or some other microorganism would be a most effective killer of humans, if considered as animals, instead of something a human can see.

Comment: But an amoeba wouldn't work as a crowd control deterrent nor as a rescue animal.